# paypal only available until the amount x

Tags: paypal

I need a solution that paypal only is available until the amount x.

Like

If amount > 1234 then {
paypal = false ;
}else{
};

Has anyone a solution for this?

Many thanks

Comment: see the ans for same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097210/magento-module-with-payment-restriction

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is implemented for offline payment methods like Bank Transfer. You can copy paste the implementation of it into PayPal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event `payment_method_is_active` and implement your own observer.

Add this inside of the `config.xml` of one of your modules. If you don't have any, create one. The code should go under the `<global>` tag.

```
<events>
    <payment_method_is_active>
        <observers>
             <[namespace]_[module]>
                 <class>[module]/observer</class>
                 <method>checkPaypalValue</method>
             </[namespace]_[module]>
        </observers>
    </payment_method_is_active>
</events>
```

Then create the observer.

`app/code/local/[Namespace]/[Module]/Model/Observer.php`

```
<?php
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer 
{
    public function checkPaypalValue($observer) 
    {
        $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
        if (!$result->isAvailable) {  //if method already inactive, do nothing
            return $this;
        }
        $methodInstance = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();
        if ($methodInstance->getCode() == 'Paypal method code goes here') {
            $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
            if ($quote->getGrandTotal() > 1234) { //if total over desired amount, disable the method
                $result->isAvailable = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```